# .htaccess redirect URL last part to same URL query strings value?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

In my `wordpress` site I need do do below redirect.

`http://www.mydomain.com/magazine-landing/lon-mayf/` to the `http://www.mydomain.com/magazine-landing/?code=lon-mayf`

Here `lon-mayf` can be anything.

I've tried below code in `.htaccess` file after `# END WordPress` but it is not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^magazine-landing/*$ www.mydomain.com/magazine-landing/?magcode=$1 [R=301,L]
```

How could I do this redirect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule's are executed in the order they appear. The rule for wordpress matches all requests, so it will never reach your rule. Besides that, your rule doesn't really do what you describe it should do.

Place this rule **above** the wordpress rule and **below** `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^magazine-landing/([^/]+)/?$ /magazine-landing/?code=$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

Replace the `R` flag with `R=301` after you are done with testing to make it permanent. Testing with permanent redirects can have unexpected outcomes due to caching.

Comment: Thanks but `lon-mayf` is dynamic text. it can be anything. So wow could I do that then?

Comment: By using a capture group. `[^/]` matches any character but the `/` character. `$1` is replaced with the first capture group.

Comment: This is work. "Replace the R flag with R=301 after you are done.." Not clear this. when should I do that? is any problem with only R ?

Comment: `R` is a temporary redirect. The fact that the client is redirected now doesn't mean it will redirect to the same place the next time, or redirect at all. A permanent redirect is (sometimes) cached for performance reasons. It also tells the client to use the new url in the future. I believe it makes a difference with search engines such as google.